# how to serve list of static files in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, static

is it possible to serve a list of static files from a given directory in django through templates. Eg. www/example.com/files/path/to/file/ should give a list of all files in the given directory and www/example.com/files/path/to/file/filename.ext should serve the requested file

Answer (score 0):

You would need a pure python implementation in the view or write your own template tag to do this.

Basically your after something like:

```
import os

def your_view(r):
    path = '/absolute/path/to/dir/'
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(
        os.path.join(path, f))]
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {
        'files': files})
```

Something like this perhaps?

You could use a similar approach in a template tag.